# How can i set another form field based on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, checkbox

I have two check boxes one is to send now and the other is to schedule the send and set the date and time. How do i just let one check box option to be selected and make sure the date and time has been selected if the send at check box is selected?

[image]

Comment: You should use radio button instead of checkbox.

Comment: thx :) how silly i am, i totally forgot about radio types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case use `RADIO` instead of `CHECKBOX` and make sure the two RADIO's have the same name so that only can can be selected at any time like:

```
<input type="radio" value="1" name="scheduler">Send Now
<input type="radio" value="2" name="scheduler">Send At
```

You can get the selected radio value by:

```
$('input[name=scheduler]:checked').val();
```

And put an `if` condition like:

```
if( $('input[name=scheduler]:checked').val() == 1 )
{
    // Do some thing here
}
else
{
    // Do some thing here
}
```

Comment: how should i do the time part?? to make it simple for the date and time i am using only one field the dateandtime .

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want ?

Comment: i mean if "send at" radio button is selected then show the dateandtime input.

Comment: So what is the issue with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138181/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-mikethetechy).